# Division of two sub queries in SQL

Tags: sql, metabase

I'm working on this query in Metabase where I want to calculate a ratio out of two sub queries. But somehow the query doesn't load but also doesn't show any error. I'm a beginner, so I'm a bit lost here. The aim for a graph that looks something like this in metabase.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Olgbp.png). Any help is highly appreciated, thanks.

```
select
to_char(ofr.created, 'YYYY-MM') as month,
(sum(
    case when ae. "type" = 'OfferRequestStatusChanged'
    and ae.data ->> 'oldStatus' = 'New'
    and ae.data ->> 'status' = 'UserUnreachable' then
        1
    else
        0
    end)::decimal / 
sum(
    case when ae. "type" = 'OfferRequestStatusChanged'
    and ae.data ->> 'oldStatus' = 'New'
    and ae.data ->> 'status' = 'Validated' then
        1
    else
        0
    end)::decimal) as "ratio"
from
    "application_event" ae
    join "offer_request" ofr on ofr."id" = (ae.data ->> 'offerRequestId')::int
    left join "offer_request_industry_sectors_industry_sector" oris on oris."offerRequestId" = 
    ofr."id"
    left join "industry_sector" ids on ids."id" = oris."industrySectorId"
where
    ids."key" not in ('DEVICE_SERVICE', 'ESTATE_AGENT', 'MORTGAGES', 'FINANCE_CONSULTING', 
    'SEARCH_MANDATE', 'RENOVATION_COACH', 'RENT_TO_BUY_CONSULTING')
    and ofr."status" != 'Deleted'
    and ofr."userEmail" not ilike '%@mailinator.com'
    and ofr."created" > '2021-06-01'
group by
    to_char(ofr.created, 'YYYY-MM')
```

Comment: Try removing `else 0` from the denominator in your 2nd case expression. That will prevent divide by zero errors.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately it's still not working :/